# Validate user's date of birth while registering, but not for Facebook and Google login in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to check the condition for date of birth above 18.

If I validate it then Facebook and Google logins are not working.

If i leave the validation, then email registered users are able to register without entering date of birth. How can I do it ?

My **user.rb**,

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable, omniauth_providers: [:google_oauth2, :facebook]

  validates :fullname, presence: true, length: {maximum: 40}  
  validates :password,  :format => { :with => /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])/, :message => "Password should contain at least 6 characters, one upper case, one lower case and one numeric." }, on: :create validates :password,  :format => { :with => /(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])/,       :message => "Password should contain at least 6 characters, one upper case, one lower case and one numeric." }, on: :update, allow_blank: true

  #validates_date :date_of_birth, :before => lambda { 18.years.ago },
  #                           :before_message => "must be at least 18 years old"

  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100#" }
  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(provider: auth.provider, uid: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
      user.fullname = auth.info.name
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.image = auth.info.image
      user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
    end
  end

end
```

If I delete the # before validates_date then Facebook and Google logins are not working. Is there another way to validate the date of birth for registering the user ?

Comment: you can just skip date validation when signup from google or facebook

Comment: Can you please write the syntax and where can i put that

Comment: you can use @pascal answer, I have update his answer that was right way to do that, if you any problem with that let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `if` option for validation:

```
validates_date :date_of_birth, :before => lambda { 18.years.ago },
                           :before_message => "must be at least 18 years old",
                if: :validate_date_of_birth?

def validate_date_of_birth?
  !(provider == 'google' || provider == 'fb')
end
```

Comment: what logic i have to write, i m new to rails

Comment: I've updated my answer. The validation will be skipped if this method returns false. So make sure it returns false for facebook and google and true for email.

Comment: and by "not working" you mean? error messages, wrong behavior?

Comment: It is not validating for email as well

Comment: what is the value of "provider" for email registered users? What version of the code do you use? (it has been updated since)